# You must implement a default accessor on System.Configuration.ConfigurationLockCollection because it inherits from ICollection

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I have been looking online for quite some time about this error.  I cannot seem to be able to figure this one out.

I have a web service created with vb.net in vs 2010.  Here is a look at my property

```
Public Class MyClass
  Inherits ConfigurationSection
  Protected _score As Integer

 <ConfigurationProperty("score", DefaultValue:="12", IsRequired:=False), _
 IntegerValidator(ExcludeRange:=False, MinValue:=6, MaxValue:=24)>
 Property gt_score() As Integer
     Get
         Return CType(Me("score"), Integer)
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As Integer)
         Me("score") = value
     End Set
 End Property
End Class
```

When I try to add this as a service to a web app, also done in vs2010 with vb.net, I get the error in the title.  Please help with this.  I am not sure what is needed in order to implement a default accessor.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with a similar problem myself.  I have a class that inherits from ConfigurationSection but I get the same error message when I try to use it in conjunction with XMLSerializer.

I believe this issue cannot be addressed within your class.  The problem lies with the properties of the ancestor (ConfigurationSection).  It has 4 public properties of type ConfigurationLockCollection (namely LockAllAttributesExcept, LockAllElementsExcept, LockAttributes and LockElements).  During serialisation, the serializer finds that these properties implement ICollection but do not have the required default accessors, hence the exception.

For my part I have tried shadowing these 4 properties and decorating them with the XMLIgnore() but still get the same problem.  AFAIK it will not be possible to serialize any class that inherits from ConfigurationSection until MS adds the default accessor to ConfigurationLockCollection.

For now I will be implementing my own methods that serialize just the properties I need from my customised configuration section.

Comment: I think this might be an abandoned question as it appears to have been answered at http://forums.asp.net/t/1680655.aspx/1?You+must+implement+a+default+accessor+on+System+Configuration+ConfigurationLockCollection+because+it+inherits+from+ICollection

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with VB.net, but in general, ICollection is an interface class.

An interface describes the methods and properties that classes inheriting from the interface need to define.  In your case, your derrived class `MyClass` needs to define a default accessor.

What if you try:

```
get
{
   return this; 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I can just add any property and put Default inf from and I am good?  I just tried that and it did not work.  I added a property of type integer.

Comment: I just tried the following with no luck Default Public Shadows Property Item(ByVal index As Integer) Get Return MyBase.Item(index) End Get Set(ByVal value) MyBase.Item(index) = value End Set End Property

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar enough with VB to offer anything more than general advice ... but I marked my answer as community wiki, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.  I resolved it by creating an XML wrapper object that just contains the properties I want to serialize and create two methods that map from the the unserializable object (a custom configuration element derived from ConfigurationElement) to the Attribute object and back.
I can then serialize/deserialize a collection of the simple objects.

See [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537746/307968) To [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19830373/307968)